# Markdown for literal [] in question/answer boxes?

Tags: support, markdown

In a Stackoverflow question/answer box, what is the [markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/markdown) to render this, not as a code fragement, but in normal narrative text.

```
myArray[2][1]
```

The above is only shown in a code fragment, as that is the only way I know how to show it to you. If instead I write the same text in normal narrative, this is what I get...

myArray[2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/markdown)

Perhaps there is some markdown to achieve this? Thanks if you can advise.

---

#### Testing Murgatroid's solution

myArray[2][1]

Comment: I'm curious why you would want to do that. The inline code syntax (backticks) is made for precisely this sort of thing. Can you explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a backslash (`\`) to escape the brackets: "myArray[2][1]" can be written like

```
myArray\[2\]\[1\]
```

or, as you pointed out, you only have to escape the open bracket, so the following will generate the same output

```
myArray\[2]\[1]
```

Comment: Thanks. With a bit of testing, I found that only the [ needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have any links using the `[]` notation, this is rendered literally:

myArray[2][1]

You can still have links using inline syntax:

`[Google](http://www.google.com)`

[Google](http://www.google.com)

or

`[Yahoo][yahoo!]`

`[yahoo!]: http://www.google.com`

[Yahoo](http://www.google.com)

Comment: Helpful, but it's a pain to change the link syntax. Murgatroid's solution is a better fit for my needs. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks (`` ` ``) for inline code.

**Markdown:**

```
Blah blah `myArray[2][1]` blah blah...
```

**Result:**

Blah blah `myArray[2][1]` blah blah...

Comment: he did ask specifically how to write brackets *outside* of code blocks

Comment: @murgatroid99: I'm assuming he meant outside _paragraph-level_ code blocks.

Comment: could be. I didn't think of that